# Chaining queries in Play! Framework

Tags: activerecord, playframework, method-chaining

is there a way to chain queries in the "Play!" framework instead of manually writing a query ?

Something like:

> Model m = Model.where("name","Bill").where("gender","m").first();

I wonder because I recently switched from [Codeigniter + dmz](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html) to [grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.4%20Querying%20with%20GORM) then now to ["Play!"](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jpa#finding) and have been a bit disappointed by the queries chaining compared to the framework mentioned above

PS: I'm obviously not talking about the *fetch()* and the *from()* methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a JpqlSelect object with wich you can do

```
public static Model findBill() {
    JpqlSelect select = new JpqlSelect().from("Model").where("name=?").param("Bill").andWhere("gender=?").param("m");
    return find(select.toString(), select.getParams().toArray()).first();
}
```

This helper is far from being complete but it may suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with java.persistence Criteria API like that:

```
CriteriaQuery q = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Model.class)
q.where(<Expression>).where(<Expression>);
TypedQuery<Model> tq = JPA.em().createQuery(q);
List<Model> result = tq.getResultList();
```

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) for start

Answer (score 1):

An other option could be using http://www.querydsl.com/ with it's jpa integration.

Comment: not sure if it would plug in nicely into the play 1.x build system

Comment: It seems to be [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490384/querydsl-and-play-framework) I chose another answer (because of the form) but yours is probably the most powerful.