# Configure QueryDSL on Play 2 Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, querydsl

I try to configure [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) in Play Framework (with Java) but without success.
I've searched for similar problems in Google and this is what I found:

**1.** [QueryDSL and Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490384/querydsl-and-play-framework). But this post establishing the equivalence with Lombok and the solution does not work for me.

**2.** [Emulating MAVEN process](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/J-uSouMKHXk). This is what I really need to apply it to other similar modules, but does not show an example of how.

**3.** [Configure multiple modules](https://github.com/torgeir/spring-scala-mongodb-querydsl/blob/master/project/Build.scala). 
In this case includes several modules and is a bit confusing.

So, how I could configure QueryDSL in Play? Anybody could include an example of how to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got it working using [play-querydsl](https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-querydsl) with Play 2.2.2.  I followed the instructions (using 0.1.1 as the version number in plugins.sbt instead of 0.1.0) and it generated the Q* model classes to `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/querydsl`.  I use Eclipse, so I ran `play eclipse` to include this folder in the classpath.

I tried to get the APT annotation compiling to work directly in Eclipse but gave up on that.

As a side note, I compared QueryDSL and EasyCriteria and I found EasyCriteria easier to use because it more closely mirrors the user-friendly queries of Ebean.  However, if you want type safety, QueryDSL is definitely better than JPA's built-in criteria API.

plugins.sbt (Play 2.2.2):

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.code-troopers.play" % "play-querydsl" % "0.1.1")
```

build.sbt (Play 2.2.2):

```
name := "project"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  cache,
  filters,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.5.Final",
  "com.mysema.querydsl" % "querydsl-jpa" % "3.3.4",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings

playJavaSettings ++ QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLSettings

val current = project.in(file(".")).configs(QueryDSLPlugin.QueryDSL)

QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLPackage := "models"

play.Keys.lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory { base =>
   (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "*.less")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I have some time to verify it, I will mark it as "the correct answer".

Comment: Can You post Your `build.sbt` and `plugins.sbt`?

Comment: @masterdany88 I've added the files as requested.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately Your configuration files are for playFramework 2.3, and I am looking for 2.2.

Comment: @masterdany88 I updated my answer with files from an older Play 2.2.2 project.  Hopefully they help.

Comment: Thanks for Your helps. Now it works :D You save my day. I have been dealing with it for 4 days already.

Comment: Just a note to say Ebean has it's own type safe queries now via "Query beans" - http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/query/typesafe