# How to enable play-querydsl plugin in Play 2.2?

Tags: playframework-2.2, querydsl

I have problem setting up querydsl framework in play 2.2.6 with scala 2.10.3 and java 1.7

I have done installation exactly like it was in [documentation](https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-querydsl). But it doesn't work.

I am gettign an error:

```
dany@dany1L:~/git/app$ playFramework-2.2.6
[info] Loading project definition from /home/dany/git/app/project
/home/dany/git/app/build.sbt:11: error: not found: value QueryDSLPlugin
val current = project.in(file(".")).configs(QueryDSLPlugin.QueryDSL)
                                            ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Here is my project/plugins.sbt:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
// changed to support play 2.2.4 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.code-troopers.play" % "play-querydsl" % "0.1.2")
```

And my build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import play.Project._
import sbt._
import Keys._
//javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked")

playJavaSettings

playJavaSettings ++ QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLSettings

val current = project.in(file(".")).configs(QueryDSLPlugin.QueryDSL)

val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()

name := conf.getString("app.name")

version := conf.getString("app.version")+"_("+conf.getString("app.releaseDate")+")"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc, 
  javaJpa, 
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "org.jasypt" % "jasypt" % "1.9.2",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.10.1",
  "com.googlecode.genericdao" % "dao" % "1.2.0",
  "com.googlecode.genericdao" % "search-jpa-hibernate" % "1.2.0",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.3.1",
  "com.googlecode.json-simple" % "json-simple" % "1.1.1",
  "javax.mail" % "javax.mail-api" % "1.5.3",
  "javax.activation" % "activation" % "1.1.1",
  "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.5.3",
  "com.querydsl" % "querydsl-jpa" % "4.0.2",
  "com.querydsl" % "querydsl-apt" % "4.0.2",
  cache
)
```

Please give me some help.

After adding:
`import codetroopers._`
on top of `build.sbt` I am getting an error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/dany/git/app/project
error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in QueryDSLPlugin.class refers to type AutoPlugin
in package sbt which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling QueryDSLPlugin.class.
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423583/nathan)
and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005684/2794446)

Finally after few days of struggle I've make it working.

Here are my configuration files:

**plugins.sbt**

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
// changed to support play 2.2.4 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.code-troopers.play" % "play-querydsl" % "0.1.1")
```

and **build.sbt**

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import play.Project._
import sbt._
import Keys._

//javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked")

playJavaSettings

val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()

name := conf.getString("app.name")

version := conf.getString("app.version")+"_("+conf.getString("app.releaseDate")+")"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc, 
  javaJpa, 
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "org.jasypt" % "jasypt" % "1.9.2",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.10.1",
  "com.googlecode.genericdao" % "dao" % "1.2.0",
  "com.googlecode.genericdao" % "search-jpa-hibernate" % "1.2.0",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.3.1",
  "com.googlecode.json-simple" % "json-simple" % "1.1.1",
  "javax.mail" % "javax.mail-api" % "1.5.3",
  "javax.activation" % "activation" % "1.1.1",
  "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.5.3",
  "com.querydsl" % "querydsl-jpa" % "4.0.2",
  "com.querydsl" % "querydsl-apt" % "4.0.2",
  cache
)

playJavaSettings ++ QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLSettings

val current = project.in(file(".")).configs(QueryDSLPlugin.QueryDSL)

QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLPackage := "models"
```

and **build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```